# How can I launch coroutine that doesn't hold the containing function from returning?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function that should do its work but also trigger a background process. The triggered process, even though launched within the function, should not hold it from returning because it is not directly related to the work being done.

Code example:

```
suspend fun coroutiny(): String {
 coroutineScope {
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(1000)
        println("Independent thing that should not avoid coroutiny to return")
     }
 }
 return "Coroutiny return"
}


suspend fun main() {
 println(coroutiny())
 println("after coroutiny")
 delay(2000)
}
```

My Desired result in this situation would be:

```
Coroutiny return
after coroutiny
Independent thing that should not avoid coroutiny to return
```

But what I get is:

```
Independent thing that should not avoid coroutiny to return
Coroutiny return
after coroutiny
```

I know this happens because coroutineScope {...} only returns when the coroutines inside return/complete.
What I need help with is to know how to do what I want without resorting to GlobalScope.launch {...}, which I wanted to avoid as my use case does not match the documented acceptable use cases for GlobalScope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, the approach with `coroutineScope` is meant to parallelize work inside your suspend function, but all the work should be finished once you return.

If you want to launch coroutines that live longer than your function's scope, you would need to use some `CoroutineScope` in which you can launch that coroutine.

The usual approach to get a scope is to make your function an extension on `CoroutineScope`. It then becomes the responsibility of the caller to provide a coroutine scope to your function (just like `launch` and `async` are designed). Also, usually these functions are non-suspending (because suspend functions are expected to finish all the work before returning).

```kotlin
fun CoroutineScope.coroutiny(): String {
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(1000)
        println("Independent thing that should not avoid coroutiny to return")
    }
    return "Coroutiny return"
}


fun main() = runBlocking {
    println(coroutiny())
    println("after coroutiny")
    delay(2000)
}
```

Output ([try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/WZuy-frUa)):

```
Coroutiny return
after coroutiny
Independent thing that should not avoid coroutiny to return
```

If your function lives inside a component that has a lifecycle, and if it makes sense to tie the life of the launched coroutines to that lifecycle, then another option is to create a `CoroutineScope` as a property of that component, and cancel it appropriately at the end of the component's lifecycle.

```kotlin
class MyClassWithLifecycle {

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(CoroutineName("my-custom-processing"))

    fun coroutiny(): String {
        scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            delay(1000)
            println("Independent thing that should not avoid coroutiny to return")
        }
        return "Coroutiny return"
    }


    fun someCloseOrDisposeFunction() {
        scope.cancel()
    }
}
```

If you're on Android, Kotlin extension libraries provide those scopes out of the box, such as `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` in the most important components with lifecycles.

Comment: what happens if I don't have the delay(2000) call there ? Does whatever's inside the customScope still run to completion ?

Comment: Yes, `runBlocking` ensures that all child coroutines finish before returning. I left the `delay()` just because it was there in your initial code, but it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need another scope here which lives longer than your original `coroutineScope`.

```kotlin
val myCustomScope = CoroutineScope(Job())

suspend fun coroutiny(): String {
    myCustomScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(1000)
        println("Independent thing that should not avoid coroutiny to return")
 }
 return "Coroutiny return"
}

suspend fun main() {
    println(coroutiny())
    println("after coroutiny")
    delay(2000)
    myCustomScope.cancel() // Cancel the scope at the right time
}
```

Test it [here](https://pl.kotl.in/tbUpdUHOU).

**Just make sure to cancel `myCustomScope` when it's no longer needed.**

Answer (score 0):

This was the best way to achieve what I really wanted with the help from the answers I got:

```
package com.bmw.otd.validation

import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun CoroutineScope.coroutiny(): String {
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(1000)
        println("Independent thing that should not avoid coroutiny to return")
    }

    return "Coroutiny return"
}


suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    println(coroutiny(this))
    println("after coroutiny")
}
```

By doing things this way I assure that:

- Function does not wait for the completion of the launched coroutine to
  return.
- Application doesn't finished until the background work is done, which was not possible to guarantee with a new "nested scope" from my tests.

Comment: Note, making it an extension function of CoroutineScope as the accepted answer suggested is closer to convention.  It’s the pattern used in the coroutines library, and it’s easier to use in some cases, because with a non-extension function sometimes the `this` you want to use is from an outer scope and so you would have to specify which one with an appropriate `@` label.

Comment: I will edit my answer, thanks.